# Create N child processes from the same process then print PID of all child process with correlative parent process

Tags: c, linux, fork, child-process

I still dont understand why the child process with pid=11310 create child process with pid=11312

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(){
    pid_t pid[2];
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
        pid[i] = fork();
        if ( pid[i] == 0){  
            printf("[child] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
        }
    }
}
```

My expected:

```
[child] pid 11310 from [parent] pid 11309
[child] pid 11311 from [parent] pid 11309
```

But the actual results:

```
[child] pid 11310 from [parent] pid 11309
[child] pid 11311 from [parent] pid 11309
[child] pid 11312 from [parent] pid 11310
```

Comment: The `fork` creates a child process. Both the child and the parent execute from the next statement onwards. You seem to have missed that the first child will also `fork` a new process.

Answer (score 1):

The `fork()` creates a child process by duplicating the calling process and it splits a process in two from the point it is called. The child process and the parent process run in separate memory spaces<sup>1)</sup>. At the time of `fork()` both memory spaces have the same content. That means, the value of variables in child process is same as that of parent process at the time of `fork()`.

In the first iteration of `for` loop:

```
pid[i] = fork(); 
// this will create child process and both parent and child process proceed with next statement

if ( pid[i] == 0){ // only child process will enter to this if block
        printf("[child] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
}
```

The output printed:

```
[child] pid 11310 from [parent] pid 11309
```

After executing the `for` loop body, the value of loop control variable `i` will be incremented in both parent and child process address space because of `i++`.

So, in the second iteration, the value of `i` is `1` in both parent and child address space.

Now both parent `(PID: 11309)` and child `(PID: 11310)` will execute the `for` loop body and both will create a child process. Thats the reason the child process `(PID: 11310)` is creating another child `(PID: 11312)`.

```
             11309-----    --|
               |      |      |---------> First iteration
             11310    |    --|   --|
               |      |            |---> Second iteration
             11312  11311        --|
```

In the third iteration, the value of `i` will be `2` in all the `4` processes and loop condition `i<2` will result in `false` and all the process will exit.

There is a **serious problem** in your code - *what happens if parent process completed running and exits before the child process?*
In that case, the child process will become [orphan process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) and you may get the parent PID as `1` instead of original parent process ID because an orphan process may reparented to *init* process which is typically assigned the PID `1`.

To overcome this problem, you have to make parent [wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for all its child process before exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    pid_t pid;

    // You can take number of child process to be create as input from user

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("[child] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pid != 0) {
        int cpid;
        int status;
        while ((cpid = wait(&status)) > 0)
            printf("Parent (%d): child (%d) exited with status 0x%.4x\n", (int)getpid(), cpid, status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

1) There is concept called **Copy-on-Write**, which is an optimization where the page tables are set up so that the parent and child process start off sharing all of the same memory, and only the pages that are written to by either process are copied when needed. Which means both parent and child process share copy of the same data and as soon as either of them do a write, a copy is made and any change in the memory of one process is not visible in another's.